# Nested, styled spans render differently in Chrome/Firefox: bug or feature?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

The following brief HTML renders quite differently on Chrome and Firefox.  http://jsfiddle.net/aoh4fa50/8/

```html
<span><span style="border-right: solid 1px black;"></span>A</span>
```

In Firefox, I get what I expect, a vertical bar to the left of an A.  (Ff 28.0 and 31.0, Mac 10.9.4)

In Chrome, I get no vertical bar at all (v32.0.1700.19 beta).  (And Safari 7.0.6 (9537.78.2) behaves like Chrome.)  But if you make any of the following (seemingly irrelevant) changes, then Chrome shows the vertical bar:

- move the inner span to after the A (obviously the bar shows up after the A in this case)
- remove the outer span tags insert (then the bar appears where it should be)
- a character to the left of the inner span (obviously the bar shows up after that character)

Am I doing something wrong, and there's an easy way to make that inner span's border show up consistently on all browsers?  If not, and this is a Chrome bug, I'm glad to report it.

Comment: I'd file this in the Chromium bugtracker.

Comment: Actually, I think it's a WebKit issue, since it's the same in Safari, and the Chromium project doesn't list rendering bugs as a valid type to report.  So I'll report it there.

Comment: Bug report filed: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=136188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The span has nothing inside it. Chrome is actually what i'd expect. If you do something like this, you'll see something in Chrome.

```
<span><span style="border-right: solid 1px black;">&nbsp;</span>A</span>
```

That's quite freaky @Ishita - that you wrote the exact line :)

Edit:

You can do this to make it consistent in all browsers:

```
<span><span style="border-right: solid 1px black; display:inline-block; height:12px;"></span>A</span>
```

Comment: The emptiness of the span is not the problem.  See the bullet points in the original question, which explain that repositioning the empty span causes the border to be shown.

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, thank you!  (Your edit, that is, which shows me how to make it consistent across browsers.)  If we later determine this is a Chrome bug, I'm glad to report it, but as far as I'm concerned, I have a workaround--thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Chrome does not apply any styling to a DOM element which is empty and its existence does not really affect any other component on the page.

So, if you add something to your first span which actually has border, it will fix.

For instance you can add 1 space by adding `&nbsp;` to that `span` element

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/aoh4fa50/9/

```
<span><span style="border-right: solid 1px black;">&nbsp;</span>A</span>
```

Hope, I am able to explain my idea through.

By the way, why do you need extra empty DOM element just to add border on the left?

You can do this to get the same output

```
<span style="border-left: solid 1px black;">A</span>
```

Comment: so which one is compliant?

Comment: I agree with Ishita. Why would you add another empty span to get border?

Comment: @Ishita Your first statement is incorrect.  Chrome applies the style most of the time, as explained in the bullet points in the original question.  It is this one rare positioning of the empty element that is the problem.

Comment: @Brunis: I think if you are adding that empty span just to add border, go with the second option - <span style="border-left: solid 1px black;">A</span>

Comment: @user3566643 and Brunis: As to why I need the extra, empty element:  I'm simulating a cursor, which may move about the document.  It's handy if the cursor is represented by its own element, rather than merely a moving decoration on other elements.

Comment: I don't care what he did and what works, it seems to me Chrome has a bug, the border should be there, empty elements are not to be ignored visually by w3 standards.